# Renaming controllers in Rails and cleaning out generated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was following along with the railscast regarding the restful_authentication plugin.

He recommended running the command:

script/generate authenticated user session

Which I did, and everything generated "fine", but then sessions wouldn't work. Checking the site again, he mentions a naming standard and listed updated code which stated:

script/generate authenticated user sessions

With sessions being pluralized.

So now I have session_controller.rb with a SessionController in it, but I guess by naming standards, it is looking for SessionsController, causing the code to fail out with the error "NameError in SessionsController#create "

I see the problem, which is pretty obvious, but what I don't know is, how do I fix this without regenerating the content? Is there a way to reverse the generation process to clear out all changes made by the generation?

I tried just renaming the files to sessions_controller with e SessionsController class, but that failed.

While writing this, I solved my own problem. I had to rename session to sessions in the routes file as a map.resource and rename the view directory from session to sessions, and update session_path in the html.erb file to sessions_path.

So I solved my problem, but my answer regarding removing generated content still remains. Is it possible to ungenerate content?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `script/destroy` works for any generator - generators work by reading a script of sorts on what files to create; `script/destroy` just reads that script in reverse and removes all the files created, as long as you give it the same arguments you passed to `script/generate`.

To sum up: `script/destroy authenticated user session` would have removed all the generated files for you, after which you could have run `script/generate user sessions` without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried `script/destroy`, but if you're reverting changes that you just made, the generate command should give you a list of files added and changes made.  If you're using a version control system of some sort, running status/diff might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just roll back to the previous revision in subversion, and start again, right? right? :-)

rails has `script/destroy` for 'ungenerating' stuff, but I suspect that will only work for the stuff rails ships with, not the restful authentication plugin.

I'd say your best bet is find-in-files (or `grep -R` if you're not using an IDE) - find everything that refers to your old SessionController and change it

Answer (score 0):

Updated for recent versions of rails:

```
rails destroy model SlackAccount user:references
```

See `rails destroy --help`